# Cypher query with ORDER BY on translation with fallback

Tags: neo4j, internationalization, cypher

I have the following data model:

- node entity `BusinessObject`
- node entity `Translation` containing a `language` and a `text` property
- relationship `TRANSLATES` from translation to the business object, potentially multiple

The translations allow me to present texts appropriate to the users language. For example, a user is able to read German, a business object is translated into English and German, then the UI displays German. In general, there's a fallback from the user's language to a default language (English).

Now, I would like to query for all `BusinessObject`s and order them by the translation which should include the fallback. Is that even possible with cypher?

**EDIT: Example**

BusinessObject *A* with Translations ("en", "XYZ English translation for A") and ("de", "Deutsche Übersetzung für A").

BusinessObject *B* with Translations ("en", "Some English translation for B") and ("fr", "Traduction français pour B").

A user *U1* has language German ("de") and the fallback should be English ("en"). So, querying for business objects should result in list [*A*, *B*] because translation "Deutsch... für A" is before "Some En...for B" lexicographically when ordering ascending. On the other hand, when a second user *U2* has language French, the result should be [*B*, *A*] because "Traduc... pour B" is before "XYZ Eng... for A". A third English user *U3* should get result [*B*, *A*] because translation "Some... for B" is before "XYZ... for A".

So I really need the ordering done by the database if that is possible.

**EDIT: Solution**

With the great ideas from the answers, I came up with the following query:

```
MATCH (r:BusinessObject)
WITH r
OPTIONAL MATCH (r)<-[TRANSLATES]-(t:Translation)
WHERE t.language = 'de' // user language
WITH r, t.text as t1
OPTIONAL MATCH (r)<-[TRANSLATES]-(t:Translation)
WHERE t.language = 'en' // fallback
WITH r, coalesce(t1, t.text) as sort
RETURN DISTINCT r ORDER BY sort;
```

Surely, this hasn't best performance but that's ok for me. Thanks to all contributers!

Comment: Can you share inputs to this, and an example of desired output, and any attempt you've made so far on a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a way to set the `ORDER BY` like that. But short of finding an answer for this if it exists, another option might be to just return you fallback separately.

```
WITH "English" as fallback 
MATCH (b: BusinessObject)-[:TRANSLATES]-(FBTr: Translation)
WHERE Translation.language = fallback
WITH fallback, FBTr, b
MATCH (b)-[:TRANSLATES]-(tr: Translation)
WHERE Translation.language <> fallback
RETURN collect(tr) as Translations, FBTr as Fallback
```

**EDIT**
Here's a simpler idea that sorts by language, putting the fallback last:

```
WITH 'English' as Fallback
MATCH (b:BusinessObject)-[:TRANSLATES]-(t)
WITH t, CASE t.language 
   WHEN Fallback THEN -1
   ELSE 0
END as sort
RETURN t ORDER by sort DESC, t.language
```

Maybe this is closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: I really need the `ORDER BY` including the fallback.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich , I added an edit that does what i *think* you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OPTIONAL MATCH` with coalesce to do what you want.

```
MATCH (b:BusinessObject)
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)-[:TRANSLATES]-(t:Translation)
RETURN coalesce(t.language,'English')
```

Comment: Will this just return the string 'English' or the English translation node?

Comment: I would like to have it ordered by the translation, so this doesn't really fit my question. Also, this would return the language and not the translation.